# A bug in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble finding a bug in my JavaScript code. It tells me a runtime error has occurred: `Expected ')'`

Here is the code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="./projects/project">                      
    <script LANGUAGE='Javascript'>                  
    x = 0;
    if(x == 0) {
        document.write("<td style="background-color:#76787A" ><xsl:value-of  select="weight"/></td>")
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("<td><xsl:value-of select="weight"/></td>")
    }
    </script>                       
</xsl:for-each>
```

What do you think?

Comment: There are three valid answers to this question. Please accept your preferred answer by clicking the tick next to an answer.

Comment: I recognize the string problem,I fixed it but I still get the same error... :s

Comment: If you still get the same error then you haven't fixed the problem.
However a different issue, if you use a Mozilla browser like Firefox, is that document.write in XSLT stylesheet generated HTML is not supported, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not escaping your strings properly. If you look closely, the syntax highlighting here on SO shows you the problem.

Use escaped `\"` or single quotes `'` when using quotes inside a string.

```
document.write("<td style='background-color:#76787A' >
                <xsl:value-of  select='weight'/></td>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your document.write calls. You have a string (inside the " ") that again has " " inside of it. To Javascript this means you are closing the string, then have nonsense text to javascript, then opening the string again, etc.... You need to escape your string with a backslash like this:

```
document.write("<td style=\"background-color:#76787A\" ><xsl:value-of  select=\"weight\"/></td>")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotes in the String, or they aren't in the strings but terminating them.

```
document.write("<td style=\"background-color:#76787A\" ><xsl:value-of  select=\"weight\"/></td>")
```